# Excluding .idea directory from project pulled by git clone

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitlab, git-untracked, git-assume-unchanged

This seems like a very stupid and rudimentary question.
This seems to be due to my lack of understanding of git.

but I'm not good at English, it was difficult to properly search for an answer to this issue..

I tried to change my IDE from STS4 to intelliJ while changing my computer to mac this time.

The only thing I searched for was an answer to add content to .gitignore, which seems to only apply when creating a new project and uploading it to github for the first time.

However, the project I cloned has already been developed to some extent, and .gitignore already exists.

What I want is simple:
Excluding the .idea directory from the unstaged list on my local machine..
of course it can be done with cli, but is there a way to do it in intelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the right mouse button on **.idea** folder and do as I show on [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhd3s.png)

Comment: I think I've gotten too used to STS4.. I was looking for this after right clicking on unstaged in the commit tab.. Many Thanks!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Go to your .gitignore file and add below line in it

```
.idea
```